# JAR file in Web page execution

Tags: executable-jar

Can java application run within web page?

If i create a .jar file and i want it to place it on my website then can it be made available to run in the web page itself i.e. like an applet? Or it can be made available as a downloadable item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I can think of is using [Java Web Start](http://www.java.com/en/download/faq/java_webstart.xml), it will allow you to launch fully-featured application from the Web Browser. It doesn't allow you to run it like an applet but it allows that the end user runs a full java app without needing to install it.

Index of [JWS](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/javaws/index.html).

Comment: What about the future since Java Webstart is deprecated now?

Comment: The future is here. We are in the world where ECMAScript specification are standardized and implemented in JavaScript, business services are written in Java, running in Application servers and/or containers and applications are now written and in/using JavaScript.